# Script with jsx and script without jsx not working on the same page

Tags: reactjs

I have a page where I want to test some react code. Both scripts **are working** independently, if they are alone in the page. If I add both, the script with jsx does not work. Is there an explanation for that behavior? Is it not allowed?

There is nothing about the code. I am guessing the imports cannot live together.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>My Website</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="myroot"></div>
    <div id="myBabel"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Load our React component. -->

    <script src="js/index2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="js/index.jsx"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here the index2.js contents:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement("div", null, React.createElement("h1", null, " the list  "));
  }

}
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App,null,null),
    document.getElementById("myroot"));
```

And here a React with jsx:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    /* Initial State */
    input: "",
    reversedText: ""
  };
  /* handleChange() function to set a new state for input */
  handleChange = event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      input: value
    });
  };
  /* handleReverse() function to reverse the input and set that as new state for reversedText*/
  handleReverse = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const text = this.state.input;
    this.setState({
      reversedText: text
        .split("")
        .reverse()
        .join("")
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        { /* handleReverse() is called when the form is submitted */}
        <form onSubmit={this.handleReverse}>
          <div>
            { /* Render input entered */}
            <label>Text: {this.state.input}</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            { /* handleChange() is triggered when text is entered */ }
            <input
              type="text"
              value={this.state.input}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              placeholder="Enter a text"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <button>Reverse Text</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        { /* Render reversed text */}
        <p>Reversed Text: {this.state.reversedText}</p>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("myBabel"));
```

Like I said, the imports are working alone but both at the same time in the HTML page are not.

Comment: please add your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    class List extends React.Component {
     render() {
               return React.createElement("div", null, React.createElement("h1", null, " the list  "));
  }

}
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(List,null,null),
    document.getElementById("myroot"));
```

If you check the console logs for your code you will find this error -
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'App' has already been declared`.

You have both your components identified as `App`. So React needs different identifiers to keep track of each component. I changed one of the class name from `App` to `List`. This will work. Make sure to name your components.